# Column with comma delimited list of primary keys of same table, how to manage such mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have one `Users` table which has `user_id` as its primary key.  For some functionality purpose (it typically makes group of users), it has a `grouped_with` field, which has list of `user_ids`, comma separated.  These `user_ids` are primary keys of same table. I have kept it as a comma separated list. Are there any alternatives to this? Are any other tables needed to make relationship? If so, how?

Or in the same table, how it would be managed? Is there any solution to optimization? I'm using a relational database.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a relationship table that has one row for each user-user grouping pair.

Comment: make a group functionality is like this, it will incrementally grow as users get added to this list.

Comment: e.g. user_id 78  is grouped with 90,18. 22 after some other user (say 45 is user_id) searches this group as per his requirements he will be added to this group initiated by 78 like this  78  is grouped with 90,18. 22, 45 .            In the similar way for 90 has formed same group with 78, 18, 22 and now 45 and 45 has formed group with 45 - 78, 90, 18, 22.... I know it is not as per RDBMS, so any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I might be over-simplifying your requirement, but this is one solution (although a simple one):

```
t_users
user_id | other details
--------+--------------
78      |
90      |
18      |
22      |
45      |

t_groups
group_id | other details (there might be none)
---------+--------------
1        |
2        |
3        |

t_group_users (shows which users belong to each group)
group_id | user_id
------------------
1        | 18
1        | 22
1        | 78
1        | 90

(after user_id 45 joins the group)
t_group_users
group_id | user_id
------------------
1        | 18
1        | 22
1        | 78
1        | 90
1        | 45
```

Comment: I was thinking of similar to what @user2867342 have answered , little modification is like this,

Comment: group_id would be part of users table only as group does not have any other details.

Comment: user and group are separate things. They should have their own tables, even if there is no information in there. The table is needed to identify the group - it's just good practice. Alternatively, you can have a 'group number' - works the same as group_id but doesn't need a table. Means you would have to allocate a unique number yourself; with the group table, this job was done for you.